# MongoDB, embedded documents indexing

Tags: performance, mongodb

I have a mongoDB collection with more than 1 million documents structured as follows:

```
{ _id:"..", 
  title:"…", 
  year:…, 
  authors : 
    [{_id:"...", mail: "…"}, 
     {_id: …, Name : "…"}, …]
 }
```

I ran the query

```
db.papers.find({"authors._id": /Stonebraker$/}, {_id:1})
```

with and without an index on authors._id

```
(db.papers.createIndex( { "authors._id": 1 } )).
```

The query should return about 100 documents.

Surprisingly, the query is performed much faster without the index.

In a previous thread ([search time with index > without index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792244/search-time-with-index-without-index)), the answer given to a similar problem was that the matching result set consists of almost the entire collection. But this is not true in my case (100 documents out of 1 million).

**Without the index:**

```
query: { authors._id: /Stonebraker$/ } 
planSummary: COLLSCAN     
cursorid:43101148517 
ntoreturn:0 
ntoskip:0 
nscanned:0 
nscannedObjects:1109672 
keyUpdates:0 
writeConflicts:0 
numYields:14218 
nreturned:101 
reslen:3905 
locks:{} 
time: 12686ms
```

**With the index:**

```
query: { authors._id: /Stonebraker$/ } 
planSummary: IXSCAN { authors._id: 1.0 } 
cursorid:47336451823 
ntoreturn:0 
ntoskip:0 
nscanned:2576899 
nscannedObjects:1394747 
keyUpdates:0 
writeConflicts:0 
numYields:213058 
nreturned:101 
reslen:3959 
locks:{} 
time: 1743651ms
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: What you appear to have missed is the [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use) documentation, which explains the index usage that applies. basically an "unanchored" expression ( not bound to the begining of the string ) cannot use an idex to efficiently select a range. So your expression which is looking from the "end of" the string, still needs to inspect every entry, whether there is an index or not. The only difference being loading the index to scan, rather than the whole document of the collection.

Comment: btw isn't an index always created for the id of the collection (_id)?